# "context deadline exceeded" AFTER first client-to-server request & response

Tags: go, grpc

In a simple gRPC example, I connect to the server, request to send a text message, and in return a success message is sent. Once the server is live, the first client request is successful, with no errors.

However, after the first try, each subsequent request (identical to the first) return this error, and does not return a response as the results (the text message is still sent, but the generated ID is not sent back):
`rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`

After debugging a little bit, I found that the error

```
    func (c *messageSchedulerClient) SendText(ctx context.Context, in *TextRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*MessageReply, error) {
        ...
        err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/communication.MessageScheduler/SendText", in, out, opts...)
        ...
        return nil, err
   }
```

returns
`rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`

Here is my client code:

```
func main() {
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }

    c := pb.NewMessageSchedulerClient(conn)

    var r *pb.MessageReply
    
    r, err = pbSendText(c, false)
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.GetId())
    err = conn.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Connection Close Error: %v", err)
    }
    return
}

func pbSendText(c pb.MessageSchedulerClient, instant bool) (*pb.MessageReply, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second * 5)

    minute := timestamppb.New(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 30))


    r, err := c.SendText(ctx, &pb.TextRequest{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("DEBUG MESSAGE: Error after c.SendText(ctx, in): %v", err)
    }
    cancel()
    return r, err
}
```

and the server code is...

```
func (s *MessageServer) SendText(ctx context.Context, in *pb.TextRequest) (*pb.MessageReply, error) {
    return &pb.MessageReply{Id: GeneratePublicId()}, nil
}

func GrpcServe() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()

    pb.RegisterMessageSchedulerServer(s, &MessageServer{})

    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
    return
}

const Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123457"

// executes instantly, O(n)
func GeneratePublicId() string {
    return id.NewWithAlphabet(Alphabet)
}
```

I've tried changing the context to .TODO from .Background. Doesn't work. I am SURE it's something so simple that I'm missing.

Again, the first time I execute the application from the client side, it works. But after the first client application execution, meaning application execution and beyond -- until I restart the gRPC Server, it gives me the error.

The GeneratePublicId function executes almost instantly, as it is O(n) and uses a random number function.

Comment: When you say "after the first request" do you mean that you are running the client executable again (or are you changing the code to call ` c.SendText` again?). Please remove all of the irrelevant code from your example (aim for a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) - that includes the call to `GeneratePublicId()` in the server (if that takes 5 seconds on the second call it would explain your issue). Note that your `defer log.Printf("Now:...", time.Now()` executes the `time.Now` at the time defer executes, not when the function exits.

Comment: edited, GeneratePublicId() is O(n), it's just a random number generator, basically. Also, sorry! The defer was for logging purposes but I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me; is this exactly what you are running (I don't think it would compile as written because `minute` is declared and not used). Please test with the simplest possible version (so remove `GeneratePublicId`) and if it still does not work add the full source (including `.proto`) to your question and I'll attempt to duplicate your issue.